# на странице localhost высвечивается <#import>

Tags: java, freemaker

тестирую приложение и на главной странице localhost высвечивается <#import "parts/common.ftl" as c> <@c.page>

common:

```
<#macro page>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <title>Sweater</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <#nested>
    </body>
    </html>
</#macro>
```

login:

```
<#macro login path>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">



        <title>Sweater</title>
    </head>
    <form action="${path}" method="post">
        <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
        <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
    </form>
</#macro>

<#macro logout>
    <form action="/logout" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
    </form>
</#macro>
greeting
Код:
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>

<@c.page>
    <div>Hello, user</div>
    <a href="/main">Main page</a>
</@c.page>
```

login
Код:

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>
<#import "parts/login.ftl" as l>

<@c.page>
    Login page
    <@l.login "/login" />
    <a href="/registration">Add new user</a>
</@c.page>
```

и вот что высвечивается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам надо предоставить больше подробностей. Что за сервер, какая конфигурация, что за файлы?

Comment: https://github.com/MasterArduino/TestSweater_forum

Comment: Я думаю возможно это из-за того что я использую thymeleaf и freemarker, типо они возможно не ладят друг с другом

Comment: Это тоже не является подробностями.